# Shipping methods select getting duplicated in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm building a Woocommerce shop.

In the Checkout page, right over the Order Review (**Your Order**), it appears by default a duplicated select for the shipping method/costs.

This is redundant as the user already selects the method/cost on the Shopping Cart page. And not only that, every time the user changes the shipping option in the Checkout Page, the select duplicates itself.

You can see the effect if you add a product and go to the Cart here: http://cccctanger.com/openwalls/catalog/

Any idea of what might be going on?

The ideal would be to delete the selects in the Order Review altogether, as it is redundant, but I don't see it in the Checkout page code!

```
// filter hook for include new pages inside the payment method
$get_checkout_url = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_get_checkout_url', WC()->cart->get_checkout_url() ); ?>

<form name="checkout" method="post" class="checkout woocommerce-checkout" action="<?php echo esc_url( $get_checkout_url ); ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <?php if ( sizeof( $checkout->checkout_fields ) > 0 ) : ?>

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_before_customer_details' ); ?>

        <div class="row" id="customer_details">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_billing' ); ?>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">
                <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_shipping' ); ?>
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_after_customer_details' ); ?>

        <h3 id="order_review_heading"><?php _e( 'Your order', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h3>

    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_before_order_review' ); ?>

    <div id="order_review" class="woocommerce-checkout-review-order">
        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review' ); ?>
    </div>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_after_order_review' ); ?>

</form>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_form', $checkout ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've managed it around it!

First I hide with CSS the Select(s) from the Checkout page.
They are always the same ID, so it's pretty straight forward:

```
form.checkout select#shipping_method_0{
    display: none;
}
```

Then, in review-order.php, I add a table row to display total shipping price between Subtotal and Total:

```
<tr class="order-total">
    <th><?php _e( 'Shipping', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
    <td><?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_shipping_total(); ?></td>
</tr>
```

And voilà!